# Is it better to store data in a list of tuples or a dictionary?

Tags: python

Which would be better. A list such as this:

```
list=[['o',5.3,7],['k',5,9.2],...]
```

or a dictionary like this:

```
dict={'o':[5.3,7],'k':[5,9.2],...}
```

If its not clear, I am trying to associate two decimal numbers to a letter in the alphabet.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each method?

I should add that for my specific application, I will be organizing the list or dictionary alphabetically by the letter. Perhaps a list is more easily ordered?

Comment: Look at the time complexity difference between dict and list here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Better in what way? Faster? More maintainable? Easier to implement?

Comment: `I am trying to associate two decimal numbers to a letter in the alphabet.` this sounds like a good use case for dictionaries from a what data structure matches my intent better standpoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to associate something to something else, then a dictionary is probably what you want. It is faster, and, well, the right tool for the job.

Example usage:

```
dictionary = {'o': (5.3, 7), 'k': (5, 9.2)}        # Don't use dict as a variable name, it's a built-in

print(dictionary['o'])
# (5.3, 7)

print(dictionary['k'][1]))
# 9.2
```

I have replaced your lists with tuples. This saves a bit of memory (presuming you don't want to in the future associate different numbers with the letters.

However, a dictionary would not preserve the order of the letters, but it doesn't seem like you need this.

Although if all you need to do is check if a number is associated with a letter, you could optimize further, and use sets.

```
dictionary = {'o': {5.3, 7}, 'k': {5, 9.2}}

print(7 in dictionary['o'])
# True
```

However, sets don't preserve ordering.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: not sure but +1 to offset since this is a perfectly good answer imho

Answer (score 1):

it's easier to iterate over lists than dictionaries
and dictionaries do not preserve ordering, so if you want easy indexing by position, it's obvious that lists are better.

in your case however, using first position to store list "id" seems very unnatural, at least somethin I'm not used to and definetely wouldn't do myself.

Comment: Not sure I agree with *it's easier to iterate over lists than dictionaries* - they're both easy - they're just different. Since they want to reference by *value* rather than position - it's not obvious at all that lists are better

Comment: imho it's easier to iterate over lists even just because they're ordered. but I agree that iterating over dicts is not difficult, but needs more typing ;)

Comment: so eventually, I will want to organize these alphabetically by the letter. Then is it better to use a list then?

Comment: @BigBoy1337 or an OrderedDict, or a class, or a seperate list of letters in alphabetical order (or possibly none of these, could you say what you want to use it for?)

Comment: A-Z are all variables that are supposed to describe a range of values. The first number is the min and the second is the max. I am hoping that these tuples will have a lower range for a, slightly higher for b, ...., a high range for z. So I will put them on a candlestick graph to vizualize how close I got (should see small rectangles on an upwards trajectory with a=1, b=2, c=3 ... on the x-axis

Comment: @BigBoy1337 Sounds like an OrderedDict would be best then.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you are going to use the data. If all you care about is access time, then just consult the list of time complexities from @hcwhsa.

Another thing to keep in mind is that a dictionary is an unordered listing, whereas a list/tuple is ordered. This can matter for iterating, serialization, etc.